# Is it good practice to use std::move over a DLL boundary?

Tags: c++, dll, c++11

As anyone who has used DLLs on Windows will tell you, it's a bad idea to `new` an object on one side of a DLL boundary and then `delete` it on the other.  Generally one uses factory methods with DLLs to avoid this so that the object code to perform the new/delete occurs in the same object file.

Today, I was designing a new interface where I wanted to `std::move` a `std::vector<std::wstring>` from one object to another where the objects were created in different DLLs.  I was all set to do this when it occurred to me that this may mean that the `delete` may now occur in different object code than the `new` did since a different object now owns the underlying pointer.

Can anyone confirm if this is the case?

Comment: The consideration should be the same for `move` as it is for `swap`.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - Yes, good point, what is the deal with `swap` regarding DLL boundaries?

Comment: ah, you've got me there. Thinking back, I reckon the only times I've used C++ interfaces across library boundaries is in situations where we ensured that memory could be safely freed from anywhere. I would expect that it's OK if (and only if) it's OK to `new` in one dll and `delete` in the other. Hence in your case neither `swap` nor `move` is OK.

Comment: I think that the problem is not in std::move. The object exported from Dll has std::vector as part of its public interface, this breaks exported class design rules. And yes, I think that this is undefined behavior.

Comment: More general: STL objects should not pass Dll boundaries. So, the whole solution is buggy, even without using std::move.

Comment: @AlexFarber I can't find anything in the exported class rules regarding standard obects such as `std::vector`, can you post a link if you've seen this somewhere?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vcmfcatl/thread/95591485-e478-4d4b-8404-971b2c6d4989 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172396

Comment: STL object created in dll executable should not be accessed directly from another exe/dll - only through functions of dll which created it. STL object may be part of implementation, but not interface.

Comment: @AlexFarber: That applies to public interfaces. If your Foo application has a "FooPrint.DLL" which is delay-loaded when the user wants to print something, using the STL is fine. The KB article you mention applies to Visual Studio 6 and older. That's 14 years ago!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the only objects that should cross DLL boundaries are objects who's destructors (and copy constructors/assignments) don't do much. Preferably, one should only use PODs for maximum safety (thus allowing two DLLs to interface even though they weren't compiled with the exact same version of the exact same compiler).

As to what happens with the move, yes, the receiving DLL will deallocate memory allocated by the providing DLL. Which generally falls under the "not good" camp.

If you want to make it safe, you could use special allocators that allocate (and deallocate) memory from the receiving DLL. But that's generally annoying.

Comment: True iff the DLL may be compiled with a different compiler and/or settings and/or Standard Library.

Comment: What about moving around a smart plikter like unique or shared ptr? Or is that just the same?

Comment: @Johan: Those can work, but only if they have explicit destructor methods on them that call into the proper DLL.